# How to remove NA in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

> I have a matrix of 2020 X 4.  But the values from row 2000 to 2020 are
>   all NAs. I want to remove these rows and my matrix should now be a
>   2000 X 4 matrix. Is there an easy way to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just reassign the matrix selecting only the values you want

If your matrix is called `x`, and you want only the first 2000 rows

you can create a new object `newx`

```
newx <-   x[1:2000,]
```

or just reassign what `x` is

```
x <-   x[1:2000,]
```

Comment: *what* about the rows? what do you mean?